# How to sort sqlite dataBase?

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to make, history of webview.
When I set database on `listView` with `simpleCursorAdapter`, it show last added item in end of list, like that:

this is KEY_ID list:

```
   1
   2
   3 
   4 
   5
```

but I want, that last added item show in start of list:

```
5 
4 
3 
2 
1
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DESC` for fetch result in descending order and `ASC` for ascending order.

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, projection_column, null, null, null, null, KEY_ID + "DESC");
```